# rake assets:precompile not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, assets

rails-3.2.7

ruby-2.1.0-preview1 [ x86_64 ]

execute command `rake assets:precompile` but can not get any response. when compiling finished css files didn't merged,just saw code like `.right{float:right;}`

```css
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require nested_sortable
 *= require tag_it
 *= require jquery.lightbox-0.5
 *= require morris
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker
 *= require articles
 *= require messages
 *= require workorder
 *= require community
 *= require homepage
 */

/* require_tree . */
.right { float: right; }
```

⇒  rake assets:precompile

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: CarrierWave::MimeTypes is deprecated and will be removed in the future, get the content_type from the SanitizedFile object directly. (will be removed from version 0.11.0). (called from require at /Users/Saxer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)
```

/Users/Saxer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/bin/ruby /Users/Saxer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1/bin/rake assets:precompile:all RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets
DEPRECATION WARNING: CarrierWave::MimeTypes is deprecated and will be removed in the future, get the content_type from the SanitizedFile object directly. (will be removed from version 0.11.0). (called from require at /Users/Saxer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)
DEPRECATION WARNING: CarrierWave::MimeTypes is deprecated and will be removed in the future, get the content_type from the SanitizedFile object directly. (will be removed from version 0.11.0). (called from require at /Users/Saxer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0-preview1@global/gems/bundler-1.8.0/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76)

gemfile

```css
# source 'https://rubygems.org'
source 'http://ruby.taobao.org/'

gem 'rails', '3.2.7'
gem 'dalli', github: 'mperham/dalli'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'memcached'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.1.0.1'

  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end

group :development do
  # Haml-rails provides Haml generators for Rails 3.
  # Any time you generate a controller or scaffold, you'll get Haml instead of ERB templates.
  gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.4"

  # Annotate ActiveRecord models as a gem
  # USAGE
  # To annotate just your models: annotate --exclude tests,fixtures
  # To annotate routes.rb: annotate -r
  gem 'annotate', ">=2.5.0.pre1"
  gem 'pry'
  # gem 'debugger'
  gem 'pry-rails'

  # Mutes assets pipeline log messages.
  # Nothing to do, but if you want to temporarily turn on back assets' log just write:
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'wirble'
  gem 'hirb'
  gem 'pasteboaRb'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  # gem "better_errors"
  # gem 'letter_opener'
end

gem 'devise'
gem "cancan"
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.6"
gem "simple_form"
gem "thin"
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'mini_magick'
# gem 'carrierwave', :git => 'git://github.com/wjp2013/carrierwave.git'
gem 'carrierwave'
# https://github.com/huacnlee/carrierwave-aliyun
gem 'rest-client'
gem 'carrierwave-aliyun'

gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.3.1'
gem 'mercury-rails'
# Nested Set is an implementation of the nested set pattern for ActiveRecord models.
# https://github.com/skyeagle/nested_set
gem 'nested_set', '1.7.1'
gem 'bluestorm_sms', '0.0.4'

# Whenever create cron jobs using Ruby, Cron is a common solution for recurring jobs.
gem 'whenever', require: false
gem "ckeditor", "3.7.1"
# rubyzip is a ruby library for reading and writing zip files.
gem 'rubyzip'
# xlsx generation
# https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails
gem 'axlsx_rails'

gem 'fastercsv'
gem 'spreadsheet'

gem "nested_form"
# amoeba is a ruby gem to allow the copying of ActiveRecord objects and their associated children, configurable with a DSL on the model.
# https://github.com/rocksolidwebdesign/amoeba
# gem 'amoeba'
gem "httparty"

gem 'exception_notification', :require => 'exception_notifier'
# Long requests should be moved into a background process.
# Delayed Job is one of the easiest ways to do this because it works with an Active Record database.
# https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job
# http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job-revised
gem 'daemons'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem "delayed_job_web"

gem 'china_region_fu'
gem "rails3_acts_as_paranoid"
# Whitelist-based Ruby HTML sanitizer.
# https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize
gem 'sanitize'

# AutoStripAttributes gem for Rails helps to remove unnecessary whitespaces from ActiveRecord or ActiveModel attributes.
# https://github.com/holli/auto_strip_attributes
gem "auto_strip_attributes"

gem 'best_in_place'

# https://github.com/pencil/encrypted_id
gem 'encrypted_id'

# https://github.com/chadlwm/ip_reverse
gem 'ip_reverse'
# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'igetui-ruby', require: 'igetui'
# gem 'aliyun-mqs', github: 'wjp2013/aliyun-mqs'

gem 'rake', '~> 10.1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

1) `rake assets:precompile` just compile your resources from `app/assets` to `public/assets`. So, try to remove `public/assets` and run `rake assets:precompile`. You should see compiled resources in `public/assets`.

2) In `development` environment Rails doesn't serve compiled assets. It is compile it in runtime and serve all resources separately. Is it mean that then you looking at `application.css` in browser you see only content of this resources. Other resources will be in other resources (look at `head` section of your HTML page)

3) If you want to serve compiled resources from `public/assets` in `development` environment (I don't understand why you want it, but ok) you should specify `config.serve_static_assets = true` in your `config/environments/development.rb`

FYI: I recommend to read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) article about Assets Pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

```
# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
 config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

In your production.rb file please check above both are true if not then do it and precompile.

Comment: If you got any error then please paste or  replace last line .right {float: "right"; }

Comment: see the warning above

Comment: can you post your gemfile?

Answer (score -2):

config.server_static_assets = true in your environment file won't work, especially if you're using heroku.

I had this issue and tried a lot of things. Uninstall & install gems back. Here's what did the trick:

```
rails assets:precompile
```